# How can I delete jenkins jobs that are older that n days

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-cli

All,

I want to delete jenkins job that are older than 90 days. I know I can do that manually using console, but is there way I can list those jobs and delete those jobs using console.

Appreciate any leads.

Comment: Do you mean builds or jobs?

Comment: Jobs. I want to have a script that list jobs and then delete those jobs.